# Integration test in python

Tags: python, testing, integration-testing, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I have a python project that I want to test. I already have unit test with `unittest` but I need to do integration tests.

For that, I have two applications: the real one that I have to test, and a "testing" application that will send requests to the first one, wait for the response and then compare it with the expected result:

[image]

Like that I wil be able to test if the application is responding correctly to the requests.

For the moment, I have what I described above, but in the main.py (not a specific test file). Also, the comparaison is just done with print function, so that I can see that it works. But I have to execute these tests and be able to get results in a conventional format, like junit xml.

How can I write, run and get results of these tests ?

**EDIT**

I'm developing an Azure IoT Edge Module, and I'm using Route to wire the modules. Here is the code of the testing module, where I need to execute tests:

```py
import random
import time
import sys
import iothub_client
import json

# pylint: disable=E0611
from iothub_client import IoTHubModuleClient, IoTHubClientError, IoTHubTransportProvider
from iothub_client import IoTHubMessage, IoTHubMessageDispositionResult, IoTHubError

# Callback received when the message that we're forwarding is processed.
def send_confirmation_callback(message, result, user_context):
    print ( "Confirmation[%d] received for message with result = %s" % (user_context, result) )

# receive_message_callback is invoked when an incoming message arrives on INPUT queue
def receive_message_callback(message, hubManager):
    message_buffer = message.get_bytearray()
    size = len(message_buffer)
    message_text = message_buffer[:size].decode('utf-8')
    data = json.loads(message_text)
    result = data["result"]
    print ("expected_result: %d; result: %d ==> %r" %(EXPECTED_RESULT, result, EXPECTED_RESULT==result))

class HubManager(object):
    def __init__(self, protocol=IoTHubTransportProvider.MQTT):
        self.client_protocol = protocol
        self.client = IoTHubModuleClient()
        self.client.create_from_environment(protocol)
        self.client.set_option("messageTimeout", MESSAGE_TIMEOUT)
        # sets the callback when a message arrives on INPUT queue.
        self.client.set_message_callback(INPUT, receive_message_callback, self)

    # Forwards the message received onto the next stage in the process.
    def forward_event_to_output(self, outputQueueName, event, send_context):
        self.client.send_event_async(
            outputQueueName, event, send_confirmation_callback, send_context)

def main(protocol):
    try:
        hub_manager = HubManager(protocol)

        # Send request 
        message = "{\"param1\": %d,\"param2\": %d}" % (PARAM_1, PARAM_2)
        msg_txt_formatted = IoTHubMessage(message)
        hub_manager.forward_event_to_output(OUTPUT, msg_txt_formatted, 0)

        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

    except IoTHubError as iothub_error:
        print ( "Unexpected error %s from IoTHub" % iothub_error )
        return
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ( "IoTHubModuleClient sample stopped" )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(PROTOCOL)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the edgehubdev Tool? https://github.com/Azure/iotedgedev

Comment: How can it help me ?

Comment: You can use it to run and test one more more modules against a local simulator of Edge Hub. You can inject messages via REST to the EdgeHubDev which get routed into your module. Then you can also see the resulting messages as they come back into EdgeHub from your module. See for more information here: 
https://pypi.org/project/iotedgehubdev/ (Quickstart)
And here for general testing approaches: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/development-environment#testing-tools

Answer (score 6):

It depends a bit on the application you are testing.
Let's say your application is an API, then the integration test could be simply calling the different endpoints and comparing the results.

You could make an IntegrationTest class with the proper write_result functions.

So a function could be:

```
def test_get_users_status(self):
    expected_result = { "user1": "active",  "user2": "inactive" }
    r = requests.get('https://localhost:8080/get_users_status', auth=('user', 'pass'))
    assert r.status_code is 200
    self.write_json(expected_result, r.json())
```

You can have a function in the integration class that runs all tests, all authentication related tests etc.

Comment: Ok. Actually I'm developping an Azure IoT Edge module and the way to send requests and get results is not so simple (there are callbacks). I've added the code in my question to explain how it works

Comment: @iAmoric Can you yield the function calls?

Comment: What function? I can manually call forward_event_to_output but I can't for the receive_message_callback. It's a callback function automatically called when a new message is put in the queue.